# IReport Creation Issue- Get all Months of Year

Tags: oracle, jasper-reports, crosstab

I want to create a crosstab for LeaveCount for Employees for respective Months with iReport (JasperReports). I'm using Oracle database.

The problem is, I'm getting only the months where the measure exists, I want to display all months of the year whether the measure(Leave of Employee) exists for this month or not.

Comment: Show us the method call which is fetching the months.

Comment: it is a sql query which is using to_char(leavedate,'MONTH'). This generates me the list of months which has Leave Data

Comment: i searched alternatively and found out that i need to show all the months in Oracle itself, so currently searching on the way to show all the months in oracle with no data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That solved the issue with the answer suggested by @Pu297 . Later **I got an even better method which involves no table creation** and saves trouble of creating a table every time i need to run report on a new database.

```
select a.mnth,b.leavecount from
(
     SELECT to_char(to_date(LVL,'MM'),'MM') mnth
     FROM (select level lvl from dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <=12)
) a
,(SELECT to_char(leavedate,'MM') AS MONTH,leavecount..."your query")b
WHERE a.mnth=b.MONTH(+)
```

**This is better way according to me for this issue.**
Cheers!!!

Comment: Perfect this saves us from creating new table.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a table

```
CREATE TABLE ALLMONTHS
(
    MONTHS_MM varchar2(2)
)
;
```

And insert all 12 months in this table(01,02,03,04...12). 
Now using this table form query as below

```
SELECT a.MONTHS_MM,b.leavecount
FROM ALLMONTHS a
,(SELECT to_char(leavedate,'MM') AS MONTH,leavecount..."your query")b
WHERE a.MONTHS_MM=b.MONTH(+)
```